# How to pass 'this' into a function using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have the following code which is designed to create an `onchange` event handler for all elements with class name 'State'. The only problem is that I want the element to be passed into the `StateChange` function. How can I update this JS to pass 'this' into the `StateChange` function?

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('State');
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) c[i].onchange = createEventHandler( StateChange, c[i] );
```

Edit: I forgot to provide the `createEventHandler` function. Sorry about that... Here it is:

```
function createEventHandler(fn, input) {
      return function () {
          fn(input);
      };
}
```

Also, some clarification. The purpose of the function is to obviate the need to put the `onchange` event next to each element with class name = 'State'. The result should be the same as if I were to write:

```
<select id="MyState1" class="State" onchange="StateChange(this)">
```

Comment: looks like you've done it. c[i] should be the element you're referring to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

Re your updated question: You've said that the end result you want is as though you'd done this:

```
<select id="MyState1" class="State" onchange="StateChange(this)">
```

Your quoted `createEventHandler` function does exactly that.

**Original Answer(s)**:

I'm not entirely sure I know exactly what you're trying to do. I can read the question at least two ways:

1. Inside the `StateChange` function call, you want `this` to refer to the element that changed.
2. Inside the `StateChange` function call, you want `this` to be the same as `this` where you're *setting up* your event handler.

#### Option 1: You want `this` = element within `StateChange`

You don't actually have to pass the element instance into `createEventHandler`, because when the event occurs, `this` will refer to the element because of the way you're hooking it up. But if you prefer to set it explicitly, your `createEventHandler` function could look like this:

```
function createEventHandler(handler, element) {
    return function(event) {
        return handler.call(element, event || window.event);
    };
}
```

What that does is return a function that, when the event is triggered, will call the function you pass in (`StateChange`) with `this` set to the `element` you pass in.. This uses the JavaScript [`call`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.4) feature of function objects, which allows you to define what `this` will be during the function call. You just pass it in as the first argument to `call` (subsequent arguments are passed on to the function being called).

If you want to rely on the fact that the way you're setting up the handler, `this` will already be set to the element instance, you can do away with the `element` argument:

```
function createEventHandler(handler) {
    return function(event) {
        return handler.call(this, event || window.event);
    };
}
```

That just passes along the `this` value set up for the event handler by the browser.

#### Option 2: You want `this` = `this` as of where you're setting up the handler

It's the same principle as the above, just with a different argument. In this case, you'll need to pass `this` in:

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('State');
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) c[i].onchange = createEventHandler( StateChange, this, c[i] );
```

...and then `createEventHandler` looks like this:

```
function createEventHandler(handler, thisArg, element) {
    return function(event) {
        return handler.call(thisArg, event || window.event, element);
    };
}
```

(Note I've passed in the element as a second argument to `StateChange`.)

More reading:

- *[Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)*
- *[You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)*

Comment: I updated my question in important ways to be more clear. Thanks your your help.

Comment: @Mike: No worries, hope this helped anyway. :-)

Comment: A short follow up on this... If I wanted to do the same thing for: <input type="text" onkeydown="return noNumbers(event)" />    , how can I set that up? I'm not sure how to specify to return that.

Comment: @Mike: Like this: `onkeydown="return noNumbers(event, this)"` In `noNumbers` the element would be the second argument. Or if you like: `onkeydown="return noNumbers.call(this, event)"` and within `noNumbers`, `this` would refer to the element and it would receive just one argument (the event).

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to ask how to pass 'this' from the event call. I meant to ask how to use JS to create an event handler for that element so that it returned noNumbers(event). My current createEventHander() doesn't do that. Like in the last case, I want the end result to be as if I had done this: <input type="text" onkeydown="return noNumbers(event)" />

Comment: @Mike: My "option 1" basically does that, just remove the `element` part of it; something like this: `function createEventHandler(handler) { return function(event) { return handler.call(this, event || window.event); }; }`

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName('State');
for (i = 0; i < c.length; i++) 
  c[i].onchange = createEventHandler(function(){
    StateChange(c[i]);
    });
```

Comment: This would not work, as `i` would always refer to `c.length` + 1 and thus `c[i]` is undefined. If you want this to work, use a self-executing function, which returns a new function, passing it `c[i]` from the current iteration and use it as an argument to `StateChange`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/uBhWc/1/ for an example.

Comment: Yes you are right Yoshi.   Alf, I think braces are matched, but as Yoshi says for it to work right you need to wrap things in another closure to prevent it using the value of i at the end of the loop.